# Сериализовать поле модели с null=True

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

У меня возникла подобная проблема. Поле `oilstorage_point` с `null=True` не сериализуется и выдает ошибку

> ```
> AttributeError at /getLine/
> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'address'
> ```

model.py

```
class OilStorage(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    address = YmapCoord(max_length=200, start_query=u'Россия', 
                        size_width=500, size_height=500, unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Pipeline(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    percent = models.PositiveIntegerField(null = True, validators= 
                      [MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    factory_point = models.ForeignKey(Factory,                 
                     on_delete = models.CASCADE, to_field="address")
    oilsump_point = models.ForeignKey(OilSump, on_delete = 
             models.CASCADE, to_field="address")
    oilstorage_point = models.ForeignKey(OilStorage, blank = True,  
                     null = True, on_delete = models.CASCADE, to_field ="address")
```

serializers.py

```
class PipelineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    factory_point = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    oilsump_point = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    oilstorage_point = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Pipeline
        fields = ['title', 'percent', 'factory_point', 'oilsump_point', 'oilstorage_point']

    def get_factory_point(self, obj):
       return [float(i) for i in obj.factory_point.address.split(',')]

    def get_oilsump_point(self, obj):
       return [float(i) for i in obj.oilsump_point.address.split(',')]

    def get_oilstorage_point(self, obj):
        return [float(i) for i in obj.oilstorage_point.address.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def get_oilstorage_point(self, obj):
    return [float(i) for i in obj.oilstorage_point.address.split(',')] if obj.oilstorage_point else 'None'
```